# How to fix this file related problem

Tags: c

i m reading from file line by line but when i read some garbage character like  space /r is being added i m nt getting why it is being added although there is  no such character in file from where i m reading ..i have used fread and fgets both from both i m getting the same problem please reply if u have solution for this problem

Comment: Post a sample that shows the problem, please.

Comment: Couple of lines from the file ...

Comment: And while you are at it, also post the code you are currently using, otherwise it smells to much like homework to be done.

Comment: -1 for extremely poor phrase and grammar structure. Please edit and ask a question in plain English that can be read easily.

Comment: @lorenzog Not for the first time, I wish we could downvote comments. To the OP, +1, but please post some code!

Answer (score 1):

The file was probably edited/created on Windows. Windows uses `\r\n` as a line delimiter. When you read the file, you must strip the `\r` manually. Since most editors treat `\r\n` as a single character (line end), you can't "see" it but it's still in the file. Use a hex editor if you want to see it or a tool like `od`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in text mode.

```
/* ... */
fopen(filename, "r"); /* notice no 'b' in mode */
/* ... */
```

Supposing you're on Windows ... on reading operations, the library is responsible for translating the literal "\r\n" present on disk to "\n"; and on writing operation, the library translates "\n" to "\r\n".